# Were All Off-world Humans Vegetarian In Stargate SG1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the Stargate SG1 universe, there doesn't seem to be animal life on alien human-occupied planets. The only non-plant life encountered are other sentient beings. Does this mean that any humans relocated to the alien planets by the Goa'uld had to subsist on a plant-only diet?

Comment: is this a variation of [nobody poops](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops)?

Comment: @user14111: Nice catch. It's a pet-hate of mine that 'sentient' tends to be mis-construed as meaning 'sapient' in most sci-fi material, but damned if I don't fall into the trap myself. A lot like saying "OMG" despite the fact I'm agnostic; I was clearly raised wrong, both by my parents and Lucas and Roddenberry, among others.

Comment: Let's not forget the scene where an Unas shares some crispy Goa'uld with Daniel. While it is arguable whether or not Unas are sentient I think it is well established that Goa'ulds are animals. Especially Chronos - but that might be just my opinion.

Comment: @Einer: I left that out of my answer because Unas aren't human. If I recall correctly, symbiotes aren't the only meat that Chaka eats in that episode.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I stand corrected. I've always assumed (from usage context) that sentient means "intelligent, thinking", rather than "feeling, perceiving". Sapient is much closer to what I meant, but fails to include Unas, Serrakin and other non-human intelligent aliens.

Comment: @Einer Daniel turns down the offer, plus he's from Earth. Also, we don't see humans eating Goa'uld. The only scene I remember Goa'uld being feasted on is in "Summit" (S05 - E15) where the System Lords are eating live symbiotes.

Comment: @KalenGi: It's hardly your fault that the majority of sci fi literature, film, and television gets it wrong. Part of my reason for annoyance is that it took me well into adulthood before I realised the issue myself.

Comment: "The only non-plant life encountered are other sentient beings." And the various monster-of-the-week creatures...

Comment: The thing about wild animals is that they're usually pretty good about hiding when something unknown comes wandering their way. It's a safety measure that most species learn so as to survive. It seems as though most scenes that take place outside include the chirping of unknown birds or birdlike creatures, so I would assume that much of the fauna encountered is simply hidden from view.

Comment: @user14111 How about "Did all humans in Stargate SG1 have a plant-only diet"? That would actually be more correct than vegan (vegan means not *using* any animal products).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Of course not. There are multiple cases on the series of off-world humans eating meat, though the most notable example is the [armadillo-type creature](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Abydonian_lizard) in the feature film.

Now, it is true that we never actually see an off-world human eating meat during the run of *SG-1*, but we also very seldom see them eating at all. When they are, it is usually a scene, similar to that in the film, though sharing more in common with the similar scene from *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom*, where the team shares a meal with the poor farmers/ miners/ slaves on the planet of the week, which establishes that these people are too poor/ subjugated to have easy access to meat.

This in no way implies that no off-world humans eat meat; the relative good-health of many off-world humans would preclude a non-meat or little-meat diet. It's also very difficult to believe that a high-class human, such as [Pyrus](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Pyrus) in [*Need*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Need), would not be eating meat. That same episode establishes that many planets have similar life to Earth - the joke Daniel's love-interest makes about trees being isolated to her world - which, again, would imply that there are animals worth eating on many worlds.

I do think it is very reasonable to assume that most human colonies were established by the Goa'uld as mining settlements, and it is also probable that any meat products would be confiscated by the local Goa'uld/ Jaffa or a trusted human overseer, as happened numerous times on our own planet (such as feudal lords denying nearby peasants the right to hunt on their property). There is also the problem that many off-world colonies would not have had access to the animals eaten on Earth once the Goa'uld lost control of the planet.

In [*Sacrifices*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Sacrifices_(episode)) it is established that the Jaffa have at least one ritual requiring [goat meat](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Goat). A similar creature is eaten in the [Pegasus galaxy](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Elson%27s_people). The episode [*Emancipation*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Emancipation) takes place on a planet inhabited by horse-riding Mongol warriors. While they are not seen to eat horse-flesh on-screen, it is highly-likely they did so, as to Mongolian and Turkic peoples on Earth. The [sourcebook](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/First_Steps:_The_Stargate_Unexplored_Worlds_Roleplaying_Sourcebook) for the [*Stargate SG-1 Roleplaying Game*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1_Roleplaying_Game) notes that [llamas](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Llama) were transplanted from Earth to the human-occupied planet [Gallicia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Gallicia), where they are a staple food-source (along with the aforementioned goat). The ability of the Ori-created insects in [*The Scourge*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Scourge_(episode)) to adapt to an [all-meat diet](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Meatloaf) indicates that meat is eaten on other human-occupied worlds as well. [In *The First Commandment*](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_Commandment) , Carter mentions that it's strange that there are no birds on the planet, which, again, implies that there are birds, which are likely edible, on other planets.

We also can't forget the simple fact that it is a lot cheaper, from a production stand-point, to highlight the wealth of a human by showing them eating grapes, rather than steak, and likewise it is easier to highlight a person's poverty by showing them eating a meagre salad than a strange creature. A regular series episode had a much lower budget than the feature, and what money they had was more likely to be spend on cool CGI effects or battle-sequences.

I think you're reading too much into the lack of spit-roasts on-screen, myself.

Comment: Also, out of universe, shooting a scene where people are eating meat is a nightmare, a standard 5 minute scene around a table could take a day to shoot, meat products attract flies, would quickly become inedible, which means they need to be replaced constantly, which is a continuity nightmare. In all cinema & TV 99% of scenes where you see people eat (and the food isn't part of the plot/joke/story) you only see actors putting bread or vegetables in their mouths.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: Good point. If meat is required, squid seems to be the go-to choice, probably because bugs don't like it and it's easy to make look like other things. I know they died squid blue for a *Star Trek* film.

Comment: Picking a consistency nit: "the relative good-health of many off-world humans would preclude a non-meat or little-meat diet", is not necessarily true. Off-world humans eat off-world food, and there is no obvious reason for such vegetarian food not to contain adequate protein levels. Earth foods generally don't, of course, vegetarian protests notwithstanding, but there is no obvious reason to apply this rule to other worlds.

Comment: "the relative good-health of many off-world humans would preclude a non-meat or little-meat diet" - can you please explain why off-world ecosystems in SG1 are far less suited to vegetarianism than earth diets?

Comment: @djechlin I read that as "Since off-world humans in the SG universe typically don't have the modern knowledge about nutrition necessary to choose a healthy vegetarian diet, and yet are not suffering the effects of malnutrition, it seems likely they are eating some meat." Of course, on Earth, there are some cultures that eat healthy vegetarian diets which they discovered through other means, so the statement is still a little suspect.

Comment: @tsleyson e.g. Jains in India come to mind. Vegan diets are recently invented; vegetarian diets are ancient.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Good point. Non-meat diets have traditionally been both unpopular and unfeasible on Earth due to nutritional defects and vitamin deficiencies, though there are exceptions, but the thought that off-world plants could provide the necessary nutritional value much more easily than Earth plants did't occur to me. And it should have, since I've read books dealing with such in the past.

Comment: @djechlin: Traditionally, non-meat diets tend to be fairly rare on Earth. They are possible, of course - in addition to the Jains, there are many Buddhists in Japan who have always practiced vegetarianism - but the relative scarcity of such diets, and the simple fact that one must have the good fortune to live in an area where such a diet is even possible (there's no way in hell someone living in pre-modern Russia is living as a vegetarian) means that such a diet would be unlikely.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Meat has all sorts of goodness, and we are clearly evolved to eat some meat (teeth and intestines tell the story), but the virtues of meat do not extend to supplying vitamins.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Red meat does not directly provide vitamin C, but the iron it contains aid in the absorption of vitamin C. There are other, similar benefits from other meat sources.

Comment: Meat also provides all nine essential amino acids. You can get this from certain combinations of non-meat foods (e.g rice and beans), which I assume is how Jains and other traditional vegetarians get by, but meat is the simplest way to get it.

Answer (score 3):

On the Stargate Wiki, there is [a list of foods](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Food) mentioned in the Stargate series. It contains meat based foods such as [Salisbury steak](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Salisbury_steak), but all of the meat based foods seem to be from Earth.

However, that is not to say that people didn't eat meat. It might have simply not been mentioned. For example, in the [1994 movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_(film)), there were these big yak/camel things (apparently called "[mastadge](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Mastadge)"). What do you think happens when one of them dies? Why not eat them?

Comment: "_What do you think happens when one of them dies? Why not eat them?_" Sorry, I don't want to seem like I'm being picky, but you don't eat the meat of an animal that just keels over and dies, not unless you're really desperate. Meat needs to be properly butchered, entrails and offal removed and blood drained more or less immediately to preserve meat. When livestock die on farms they're buried, we don't eat those animals, you can't even use that meat for dog food.

Comment: Agreeing with @BinaryWorier, when a cow breaks a leg, but is otherwise healthy you need a vet to certify that the meat is safe to eat before the animal is killed, or the butcher won't touch it.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier oops. I thought that so long as an animal isnt terribly sick but still drops dead, it would be eaten. Maybe I should change that sentence to something like "What do you think happens if one of them is injured too much?"

Comment: Oh dont change anything on my account :) If meat is a regular part of the people's diet then theres an whole deal of planning to raise animals specifically for slaughter, working animals tend to be too lean etc. You raise groups of animals (say cattle) until 2 yr old then slaugter when at peak for.meat, leather etc. If meat isnt a regular part of the diet then they're not likely to opportunistically naw down on working animals that keel over. I'd have said, "what do you think happens to the beasts of burden when food is scarse and folks get hungry". But dude, dont mind me :)

Comment: @calccrypto - Wait just a cotton-pickin minute here. Would you please explain "so long as an animal isnt terribly sick but still drops dead"? How sick can an animal be before dropping dead isn't a clue that something is really wrong with it?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast First: `I don't deal with animals, so sorry for all the ignorance`. I was thinking something along the lines of: eating the animal that died of a stroke (does that even happen?), as opposed to eating the remains of an animal that was so sick that its flesh was melting before it died.

Comment: @calccrypto - Nor am I suggesting that. It's just that sickness does not necessarily manifest itself as obviously as you seem to think. If an animal keels over, it might be something as benign (in eating terms) as a stroke. Then again, it might not, and it's not the sort of Russian Roulette that makes for good dietary practice.